# Increasing Call Quality Twilio + Zoom

Tags: twilio, amazon-polly

I'm having Twilio call into a [Zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoom_Video_Communications#Products_and_services) call and then interact with the other callers. It works fine, but the quality of the speech is fairly low. I tried using the Neural Polly and Google WaveNet, but it sounds much worse than when I try listening to those voices on the AWS and Google websites. My understanding is that Twilio downgrades the quality for phone calls to 8 kHz only. Is there a way to increase the quality of the speech?

I have tried different voices.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio's developer advocate here.

Usually the audio stream are of calls from the public switch telephone network using PCM (8 kHz).

At present, below are the formats that Twilio supports:

- WAV (8-bit PCM mono uLaw with a sampling rate of 8 kHz)
- MP3
- AIFF
- FLAC (Lossless)

Twilio converts everything to 8-bit with the sample rate to match the model (usually 8 kHz or 16 kHz).
However, the standard bandwidth is limited to the 300 Hz - 8 kHz audio range and is designed for voice and provides acceptable voice-quality results.

So the payload must be encoded *audio/x-mulaw* with a sample rate of 8000 and Base64 encoded.

So, with regards to Twilio Programmable Voice and the recording function, I'm afraid we only have the 8 kHz sample rate that is, at this time, the only sample rate.

For more details, please see the article: *[Best Practices for Audio Recordings](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings)*

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but I wanted to make sure I had a proper explanation to share with you for this condition.

Comment: Misspellings on [the Twilio page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings): "8Khz" (nine instances). \**[kHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz#SI_multiples)*. And "[Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz)", not "hz". And a space [should separate the quantify and the unit](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15953): \**8 kHz*. It is supposedly ***in your powers to fix it***.